# NSView's frame is 0.5 pixels off from where the constraints suggest it should be

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit

Has anyone seen something like this before?

```
(lldb) po self.constraintsAffectingLayout(for: .horizontal)
▿ 5 elements
  - 0 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000243f2f0 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[MyApp.MyCustomButton:0x7fe67e83b000'Some Label']   (active, names: '|':MyApp.MySuperView:0x7fe68d7073f0 )>
  - 1 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000243e1c0 H:[MyApp.MyCustomButton:0x7fe67e83b000'Some Other Label']-(NSSpace(20))-|   (active, names: '|':MyApp.MySuperView:0x7fe68d7073f0 )>
  - 2 : <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000024046e0 h=-&- v=-&- MyApp.MySuperView:0x7fe68d7073f0.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x7fe68d735be0 )>
  - 3 : <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002404730 h=-&- v=-&- H:[MyApp.MySuperView:0x7fe68d7073f0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x7fe68d735be0 )>
  - 4 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002426a80 'NSWindow-current-width' NSThemeFrame:0x7fe68d735be0.width == 465 priority:500   (active)>

(lldb) p self.frame
(NSRect) $R1 = (origin = (x = 19.5, y = 19.5), size = (width = 426, height = 81))
```

It appears that per the constraints, this should be 20 pixels from the edge of the screen, but instead it's 19.5. As you may expect, this is causing the button to draw all blurry on non-Retina displays.

Anyone seen anything like this before and/or know what sort of thing could cause something like this? Is there anything I should look for to debug this?

Comment: How are the button and constraints created?

Comment: Any overrides in `MyCustomButton` that might affect the layout?

Comment: @Willeke They're all created in IB. The button is an IB Custom View with the class set to my button's class (the names are obviously changed in the example). The constraints are similarly set up in IB; there's a standard left constraint and a standard right constraint. I've already tried changing them explicitly to 20 instead of Standard.

Comment: I don't _think_ there are any overrides that affect the layout, but it's probably not a bad idea to skim through and check. One moment.

Comment: .................. oh, for pete's sake ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that the custom class I was using was fine, but the custom class that was *its* superclass contained an override of `alignmentRectInsets` which was causing the issue. Leaving this here in case someone else runs into the same issue. Apologies for the noise.